# SQL/PLSQL query to get sum of difference between Start date and End date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has the following data

```
Date_from     Date_to
20-NOV-19     22-NOV-19
10-NOV-19     21-NOV-19
14-NOV-19     26-NOV-19
```

I need a query to find the sum of the difference between date_from and date_to.

**Example** 
The difference between 20-Nov-19 and 22-Nov-19 is **2 days**
The difference between 10-Nov-19 and 21-Nov-19 is 11 days but the query has to consider it as **9 days** because days 20-Nov, 21-Nov are already considered in the first row.
The difference between 14-Nov-19 and 26-Nov-19 is 12 days but the query has to consider it as **4 days**
because days 14-Nov to 22-Nov are already considered in the above rows.

The query result should be 15 days(2+9+4).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

one more variant :

```
with t as (
select to_date('20-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_from,to_date('22-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_to from dual
union all
select to_date('10-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_from,to_date('21-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_to from dual
union all
select to_date('14-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_from,to_date('26-11-2019','DD.MM.YYYY') Date_to from dual
),
alldays as
(select (select min(t.Date_from) from t)+level-1 dt  from dual connect by level<(select max(t.Date_to)+2 from t)-(select min(t.Date_from) from t))
select count(distinct a.dt)-1 from t
join alldays a on a.dt>=t.Date_from  and a.dt<t.Date_to
order by a.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: inline view fetches all dates between `CFROM` and `CTO` and returns number of distinct dates.

```
SQL> WITH test (cfrom, cto)
  2       -- sample data
  3       AS (SELECT DATE '2019-11-20', DATE '2019-11-22' FROM DUAL
  4           UNION ALL
  5           SELECT DATE '2019-11-10', DATE '2019-11-21' FROM DUAL
  6           UNION ALL
  7           SELECT DATE '2019-11-14', DATE '2019-11-26' FROM DUAL)
  8  -- this is useful code
  9  SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT datum) - 1 diff
 10    FROM (SELECT cfrom + COLUMN_VALUE - 1 datum
 11            FROM test
 12                 CROSS JOIN
 13                 TABLE (
 14                    CAST (
 15                       MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
 16                                       FROM DUAL
 17                                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= cto - cfrom) AS SYS.odcinumberlist)));

      DIFF
----------
        15

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak MySQL, @Anji007

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of a gaps and islands problem.

Here is the approach:

- Identify where a new period starts (an "island") using `lag()` or a cumulative max.
- Use the start to identify the islands, using a cumulative sum of starts.
- Aggregate the islands.
- Aggregate overall.

So:

```
select sum(date_to - date_from)
from (select min(date_from) as date_from, max(date_to) as date_to
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when prev_dt >= date_from then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date_from) as grp
            from (select t.*,
                         lag(date_to) over (order by date_from) as prev_dt
                  from t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by grp
     ) t;
```

Comment: (1) This works in MySQL 8+.  (2) No.  The question is tagged Oracle and explicitly mentions PL/SQL.  If you have a question about MySQL, ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH test (
cfrom,
cto)

AS (
SELECT
    DATE '2019-11-20',
    DATE '2019-11-22'
FROM
    dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATE '2019-11-10',
    DATE '2019-11-21'
FROM
    dual
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATE '2019-11-14',
    DATE '2019-11-26'
FROM
    dual) 
SELECT
sum(diff)
FROM
(
    SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN prev_cfrom IS NULL THEN cto - cfrom
                WHEN prev_cfrom IS NOT NULL
                     AND cfrom >= prev_cfrom
                     AND cto >= prev_cto THEN cto - prev_cto - 1
                WHEN prev_cfrom IS NOT NULL
                     AND cfrom >= prev_cfrom
                     AND cto <= prev_cto THEN 0
            END
        diff,
            cfrom,
            cto,
            prev_cfrom,
            prev_cto
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                cfrom,
                cto,
                LAG(cfrom,1) OVER(
                    ORDER BY
                        cfrom ASC
                ) prev_cfrom,
                LAG(cto,1) OVER(
                    ORDER BY
                        cfrom ASC
                ) prev_cto
            FROM
                test
            ORDER BY
                cfrom
        )
)
```